# Does a mixture model need to sum or integrate to $1$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Suppose that we have a mixture model:

$$
p_\theta(y) = \sum_{k = 1}^{K}w_k \phi(y;\mu_k, \sigma^2_k)
$$

where $\phi(y;\mu_k, \sigma^2_k)$ is the normal density at $y$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. $\theta$ contains the weights, means, and variances.

In this case and in more general cases aside from the Normal mixture, must the model sum or integrate to $1$?

Comment: You define it in terms of a probability distribution. Does a probability distribution need to integrate to 1 ..?

Comment: I see, so $\int p_\theta(y) = \int \sum_{k = 1}^{K}w_k \phi(y;\mu_k, \sigma^2_k) = \sum_{k = 1}^{K}\int w_k \phi(y;\mu_k, \sigma^2_k) = \sum_{k = 1}^{K} w_k \int \phi(y;\mu_k, \sigma^2_k) = \sum_{k = 1}^{K} w_k = 1$

Comment: If the weights sum to 1, the combined model integrates to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$$ \Pr(A)=\sum_n \Pr(A\mid B_n)\Pr(B_n) $$

and by the [axioms of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) $\sum_k \Pr(A_k) =  \Pr(\Omega) = 1$, so

$$
\sum_k \sum_n \Pr(A_k\mid B_n)\Pr(B_n) = 1
$$

In the case of mixture distribution

$$ f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i f_i (x|\theta_i) $$

where $\pi_i\ge 0$ and $ \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i=1$, it can be described in terms of conditional distribution of two random variables

$$
I \sim \mathcal{Cat}(\pi_1,\dots,\pi_n) \\
X_i \sim f_i(\theta_i)
$$

and from here you should see right away how the law of total probability applies. What follows, if $f(x)$ is a proper probability distribution it needs to integrate to unity

$$
\int \, f(x) \, dx = \int \, \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i f_i (x|\theta_i) \, dx = 1
$$